# Lazy ignored after save

Tags: java, jackson, spring-boot, spring-data

My controllers are behaving different on Spring Boot and I don't know why. I have this model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comments")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean anonymous = false;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 150)
    private String text;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date date;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Post post;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

On my controller I do:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", 
            method = RequestMethod.POST, 
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Object createComment(Comment comment, HttpServletRequest request){
    comment.setUser(userService.findByUsername(UserUtil.readUsernameFromUrlToken(request)));

    Comment persistedComment = commentService.save(comment);
    if(persistedComment != null){
        if(persistedComment.isAnonymous()){
            persistedComment.setUser(null);
        }
        return persistedComment;
    }
    return new Error(Error.NOT_CREATED, "Comment not created!");
}
```

And it returns the `post` that is annotaded with LAZY. But when I fetch in another controller, it returns the expected result (Without the lazy `post`)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/comments", 
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Object findCommentsByPostId(@PathVariable("id") long postId){
    List<Comment> comments = commentService.findByPostId(postId);
    for(Comment comment : comments){
        if(comment.isAnonymous()){
            comment.setUser(null);
        }
    }
    return comments;
}
```

On this request mapping, it returns just the `user`, as expected.
I don't know why in the first one it resturns with the lazy `post`, even if I do:

```
return commentService.findById(persistedComment.getId());
```

instead of

```
return persistedComment;
```

Comment: If you call the first controller, is the post also contained in the JSON? If so, then of course the post field will be filled with that data. Since the persisted object is then stored in the entitymanager, this object will be returned when you call the findById method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and yes, it is added because it comes from the request the `postId` to fill the relation. So it is understandable that will return the `post` too. But, why it returns the `post` even if I use `return commentService.findById(persistedComment.getId());`, because it is fetching again just using the `id` of the persisted object as same as the other request where it comes everything correctly?

Comment: AFAIK if you have a managed object in the entity manager (which you have, since you have persisted the comment in that method) and you retrieve that object by id, then the object from the entity manager will be used, which still contains the post.

Comment: I see. I think that is really why. If you can post an answer with those comments so I can accept it. And I think in the cases of save, i'll have to set to null manually the fields that I don't want. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call the first controller and the post also contained in the JSON, then of course the post field will be filled with that data. Since the persisted object is then stored as a managed object in the entitymanager, this object will be returned when you call the findById method (the entity manager or Hibernate session works as a 1st level cache).

Answer (score 1):

In your first case a new comment object is persisted and fetched in same transaction.So there is no database call to load this object.The comment object
which was persisted is returned as it is.Hibernate keep your persisted object in first level cache(hibernate session).